# undefined local variable or method page (RSpec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

## some_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication." do  
 subject { page }
 let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
 before {visit new_user_session_path}
 describe "Login with username" do
  before do
   fill_in "Login",   with: user.username
   fill_in "Password",    with: user.password
   click_button "Sign in"
  end
  expect(page).to have_content('Signed in successfully.')    
 end
describe "Login with email" do    
 before do
   fill_in "Login",   with: user.email
   fill_in "Password",    with: user.password
   click_button "Sign in"
 end
 expect(page).to have_content('Signed in successfully.')    
end
end
```

## spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

What's the problem? After run command terminal returned error: `undefined local variable or method 'page'`.

The following question did not help me:
[rspec+capybara undefined local variable or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623345/rspeccapybara-undefined-local-variable-or-method)

Comment: where have you initialized `page` variable?

Comment: @emaillenin I didn't do it. I took the examples in this guide http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-TDD .
The author did not initialize this variable. 
I hope that I am wrong

Comment: remove `subject { page }` from the spec

Comment: What version of rspec? Where is the spec?

Comment: @gotva
I deleted 'subject { page }'. It didn't help

Comment: have you wrapped expectation by `it` blocks?

Comment: @FrederickCheung spec/features/
version 2.14

Comment: @gotva yep. but there is a new bug. undefined method `before' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000001fdb1e0>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should remove `subject { page }` from your spec.

`page` is defined in [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/f83edc2a515a3a4fd80eef090734d14de76580d3/lib/capybara/dsl.rb#L45).

**Important:** wrap your expectations by `it` blocks!